# Salesforce lightning connect to connect with SAP

Tags: lightning-connect, sap

I would like to know if anyone has any experience integrating Salesforce with SAP for Business One.

I tested Lightning connect in a dev org to connect with SAP and it's working fine. despite I don't know the prices of lightning connect, In one way it's fine to use this Salesforce feature as I read, it will create external objects in Salesforce and this works for us if I'm taking about accounts or pricing. But for Invoices we don't want to use it as external objects as invoices won't change to often and we see not useful to go to SAP when we should have that info inside Salesforce (mostly for report purposes).

Does anyone knows or can recommend me how to achieve this? to keep some SAP data inside Salesforce as an object and not as an external object?

Any advice will be really appreciate it.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Did you end up continuing to use Salesforce Connect to integrate with SAP B1?

Answer (score 0):

Ask your Salesforce account team about forthcoming enhancements (Winter '17) to Salesforce reporting that will provide some access to external data for reporting via Salesforce Connect.

If you're going to use Salesforce Connect anyway, perhaps you could avoid copying data from SAP to Salesforce with these reporting enhancements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, we can't take decisions about upcoming features that there is not certainty about when or how future features will be released. Thanks for your comment...!!!

Comment: I understand that playing the "futures" card can be risky, but this is able to be piloted now, with production rollout happening with the general release of Winter '17.